# Inflate XML listview in adapter android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, android-xml

I am trying to inflate this list_item.xml, but apparently eclipse can't find list_item.xml, when I try to inflate R.layout.list_item and I also get an error when I try to find R.id.counter (the third element in the xml file).

I am not sure if there is a problem in the XML, but I really don't think so. Since I am pretty new to Android, I was guessing there could be a problem with the name of the file? list_item or an error after the first TextView, which I really can't see.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:textColor="@color/list_item_title"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/counter_bg"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/counter_text_color"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit: 
The error I am getting is the following: 
"list_item cannot be resolved or is not a field"

This is how I am inflating the file and trying to get R.id.counter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
```

Comment: And what is the error exactly?

Comment: "list_item cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: Clean ur project or restart eclipse

Comment: is it the only xml having that problem?

Comment: I have already cleaned and restarted eclipse several times. Yes, it is.

Comment: The thing is I can findViewById both "title" and "icon", when it comes to "counter", I get the same error as when I inflate the whole file; so I thought there was something wrong there.

Comment: Just check in your import, is there android.R imported?

Answer (score 1):

> This is how it should be,

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);              
TextView tvCounter = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.counter);
```

Comment: Yes, I am getting two errors on the first and third line.

Comment: "counter cannot be resolved or is not a field" + "list_item cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: You are most probably using 'android.R.layout.list_item'
Use your application's R.java file.
Check in your imports for 'android.R' and delete that line, and then import your application's R file

Comment: Shall I change the file's name, clean, restart and see if it works?

Comment: I was also importing android.R, so I think that could have caused the issues?

Comment: No, use 'your.package.name.R.layout.list_item'